# fpassthru in python?

Tags: php, python, download, urllib

I am trying to find a sample code for download a file in python. To be exact, I am trying to convert a php to python.

My php sameple code:

```
$http_request = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
$http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";
$http_request .= "User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP\r\n";
$http_request .= "\r\n";
$http_request .= $data;

$response = '';
if( false == ( $fs = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10) ) ) {
die ('Could not open socket');
}

fwrite($fs, $http_request);

$headerpassed = false;
while ($headerpassed == false) {
$line = fgets( $fs);
list($tag, $value) = explode(": ", $line, 2);


if (stristr($tag, 'Location')) {
$target_url = trim($value);
header("Location: http://127.0.0.1/umsp/plugins/".basename(__file__)."?".$url_data_string."\r\ n");
continue;
}


if (trim($line) == "") {
$headerpassed = true;
header('Content-Type: video/avi');
}
header($line);
}


set_time_limit(0);
fpassthru($fs);


fclose($fs);
```

I found python file download script using urllib, but all the examples I found actually save to physical file unlike php code above.

PS: someone please add 'fpassthru' for me. I don't have permission to add a new tag.

Comment: What are you using on the Python side?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams // I am new to Python, so I actually don't know what you are are exactly. I am using python for xbmc plugin

Comment: Where would you like the data to end up, plugin-wise?

Comment: Well, I don't want to save the data. As you see in php code above, it does not save the data. It just stream as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

A translation of PHP's `fpassthru` to Python might be as simple as:

```
def fpassthru(fp):
    """ Reads to EOF on the given file object from the current position
        and writes the results to output. """
    print fp.read()
```

The `fp` argument must be a "file object" returned by `open` (the standard method for opening files) or a similar stream factory method such as `urllib2.urlopen` in the case of downloading content from an URL.

For example, this will open an URL and print its contents:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen # (renamed to urllib.request in Python 3.0)
fp = urlopen('http://www.example.com')
fpassthru(fp)
fp.close()
```

Note that you can get the HTTP response headers with `dict(fp.headers)`. (But this attribute is only available on file objects returned by `urllib2.urlopen`, not regular file objects.)